# Stata loop function for many t tests

Tags: loops, stata

I want to reproduce the results of a study that compared means of multiple groups in Stata. I don't have the original data, but group-specific information about mean, sd and n.

In Stata, two groups can be compared using the following code:

```
ttesti n1 mean1 sd1 n2 mean2 sd2
```

There are quite a lot of groups and quite a lot of variables to compare them on, that's why I am searching for a loop function that allows me to safe code.

The key would be a loop function that does the described t test for all rows (variables that the groups are compared on) using the respective group-specific information (n, mean, sd) in the columns.

Comment: How are your data arranged? Do you have three variables (n, mean, sd) and observations corresponding to the different groups, or do you have a separate variable for each n, mean and sd of each group?

Comment: Compare http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/accumulating-results-from-immediate-commands/index.html

Comment: Further, do you want to compare the group 1 mean with all subsequent groups, or only a specific group? Should group 2 be tested against group 3 ... N or only a specific group? Please provide some more detail to your question.

Answer (score 0):

@ander2ed's good questions have not been answered.

But consider

```
forval i = 1/`=_N' { 
   ttesti `=n1[`i']' `=mean1[`i']' `=sd1[`i']' `=n2[`i']' `=mean2[`i']' `=sd2[`i']'
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your proposed syntax! However, when I run it, it results in the error message "N not found invalid syntax".